# AJAX request not returning items from the server in correct <divs>

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an overlay which appears on screen when a user clicks on an image. When the image is clicked on, a post ajax request is executed and it should return the result of `moduleID`, `moduleName` and `pageID` into the `<div id="result">` and it should also return `content` into the `<div id="content">` However I get nothing at all?

**modules.php:**

```
<div class="grid-2 dashboardIcons module">
    <h3 class="fontAmaticH1">Critical Writing</h3>
        <a class="cursor module" onclick="toggleWindow(); getModuleData(4)"><img value="4" src="images/CriticalWriting.png">
        </a>
</div>

<div id="result"> <!-- Should be returning data from db here -->
</div>
<div id="content"> <!-- and here -->
</div>
```

**moduleTestingAJAX.php:**

```
<?php

require 'scripts/db.php';

$moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];
$pageID = 1;

if(isset($_POST['moduleID']))
{


    //$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM `module` WHERE moduleID = ?");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT `module`.`moduleID`, `module`.`moduleName`,`moduleContent`.`pageID`, `moduleContent`.`content` FROM `moduleContent` INNER JOIN `module` ON `module`.`moduleID` = `moduleContent`.`moduleID` WHERE `moduleContent`.`pageID` = ? AND `moduleContent`.`moduleID` = ? ");    
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $pageID, $moduleID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $output = [];

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $output["result"] = $row['moduleID'].' '.$row['moduleName'].' '.$row['pageID'];

        $output["content"] = $row['content'];

    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
 ?>
</div>
```

**script.js:**

```
// When user clicks open a module, pass the moduleID through in an ajax request to get data from the db
function getModuleData(moduleID){
  console.log(moduleID);
  $.ajax({  
      url: "moduleTestingAJAX.php",  
      method: "post",   
      data: {moduleID:moduleID},
      success: function(data){  
            console.log(data);
            $('#result').html(data.result);    
            $('#content').html(data.content);    
      }  
  });
  console.log("test");
}
```

**What is held in the table `moduleContent`**
[image: DB Data]

**After running `console.log(data);` in the ajax call I get this returned:**
[image: output]

Comment: Add `console.log` in your success function to see what `data` is.

Comment: You put `console.log` in your PHP, please remove that, that's what causing all those errors.

Comment: apologies, I've updated the screenshot with the output :) Looks like I'm getting the correct output, however not actually in the `<divs>`

Comment: the output seems malformed. Why is there 6 in the beginning? Do a console.log(data.result) or console.log(content) and I am sure they will be empty or even throw an error.

Comment: @NawedKhan I think it's returning that because of the line `data: {moduleID:moduleID}` so I pass through the moduleID depending on which module the user selects.

Comment: if you expect more than one result you would be disappointed - you overwrite `$output["result"]` and `$output["content"]` in the loop. Perhaps `$output["content"][]=...` and `$output["result"][]=...` would be more appropriate

Comment: @RamRaider I see, so is this why I cannot return different data to two different `<div>` tags? Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: also, `$moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];` should be within the `if(isset($_POST['moduleID'])){...` condition otherwise you can get errors

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider I've altered this now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not parsing the JSON you receive. When your PHP script echoes `json_encode($output)`, you're getting a JSON encoded *string*, which you then attempt to use as an object.

There are two options, either tell your AJAX request you're expecting JSON by adding the `dataType` attribute:

```
$.ajax({  
      url: "moduleTestingAJAX.php",  
      method: "post",   
      data: {moduleID:moduleID},
      dataType: 'json', // <-- this line added
      success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data.result);    
            $('#content').html(data.content);    
      }  
});
```

Or, you could manually parse the JSON inside your success function:

```
success: function(data){
    parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#result').html(parsedData.result);    
    $('#content').html(parsedData.content);    
}
```

I'd suggest the first option.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked but only for returning the data in the `<div id="result">` and nothing appears in the `<div id="content">`

Comment: I believe that if you set additional options for the ajax request the `success` function will automagically `parse` the response data ... this might ( or might not be ) the default behaviour for jQuery(ajax) I don't know. I think you should set (?) the `type` parameter as an options??

Comment: @T.C Should work for both, considering the `console.log(data)` output included in your question.

Comment: @RamRaider That's what my first option suggests. Default behaviour is "intelligent guess"... which doesn't guess well in this case.

Comment: Please add console.log(data.content) in the success block and share what it shows. also share what console.log(data) looks like now.

Comment: @NawedKhan I get this: `6 Mindfulness` and then below `1 This is page 1 inside of the Mindfulness - 6`. So it does seem to be splitting them, just not returning them to the correct `<div>`

Comment: write some random text in your "content" div in the html. I suspect it is hidden/invisible.